# How did Vladimir Voevodsky "changed the meaning of the equals sign"?

Tags: proof-verification, popular-math

This [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/06/obituaries/vladimir-voevodsky-revolutionary-mathematician-dies-at-51.html) from The New York Times is an obituary of the recently deceased Dr. Voevodsky. It explained that he was deeply involved in developing computer proof verification, and to do so "changed the meaning of the equal sign" and "reformulated mathematics from its very foundation".

As the article is targeted to a general audience, it does not go into details.

**Can someone explain the meaning of these two quotes from the New York Times?**

(I believe they are related)

Comment: Here's a video by Dr. Voevodsky which should help clarify
$$$$
$\qquad$https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRqOVQXxQI4
$$$$

Comment: Not confident enough to provide a full answer - but in some type-based foundations of mathematics, such as variants of Martin-Loef type theory used in Coq or Agda (especially Coq for this topic, as Agda tends to assume the "$K$ axiom" by default which destroys homotopy type theory): each proposition is in fact a type itself ("a proposition is the type of proofs of that proposition").  So, if you have `x, y : A` and two proofs `e1, e2 : x = y` then it makes sense to ask whether `e1 = e2` and it's surprisingly not provable.  Then for `e3, e4 : e1 = e2` you can ask whether `e3 = e4`, etc.

Comment: That starts to look somewhat like an $\infty$-category, and specifically has analogies to homotopies, homotopies between homotopies, etc.

Comment: So, for a possible interpretation of this fact in terms of homotopies, say $A = S^1$ and you interpret `x = y` as the set of paths from $x$ to $y$.  Then for `e1, e2 : x = y`, interpret `e1 = e2` as the set of homotopies from path $e_1$ to path $e_2$, and in particular as a proposition `e1 = e2` corresponds to the two paths being homotopic to each other.

Comment: What I'm not so confident about: I've only seen some of the discussions of HoTT briefly from the outside, so I'm not sure whether my interpretation is in line with the HoTT project, or if my interpretation diverges somewhat from their development and/or focus.

Comment: Another possible approach to the correspondence: many of the common examples of homotopy spaces can be expressed as universal constructions, which are close to objects defined by "inductive construction" primitives in Coq, Agda, OCaml, Haskell, etc.  For example, $S^1$ can be expressed as the left-universal homotopy space with a base point $x$ and a path from $x$ to $x$.  So, I think they were looking at ways to reason with constructions that nominally look something like:

Comment: @Daniel Schepler: Thank you for your answers. Can you please explain more explicitly how it is related to a language of mathematics, proof verification, and foundations of mathematics?

Comment: `Inductive circle : Type := | circle_base_point : circle | circle_loop : circle_base_point = circle_base_point.`  (Even though Coq etc. don't technically allow constructors of the second type.)

Comment: @beroal Getting very conjectural here, but I think maybe in terms of mathematical foundations, they were seeing whether instead of a foundation essentially in terms of the category $\mathbf{Sets}$, maybe a foundation might work better for some purposes in terms of some $\infty$-category in which you can ask about equivalences between morphisms, equivalences between those equivalences, etc.  With a mental model of this $\infty$-category looking much like the $\infty$-category of homotopy spaces.

Comment: And in terms of proof verification, if you could express some fact in homotopy theory in terms of this category, and then use e.g. Coq to verify the corresponding theorem, then that potentially allows for formally verified proofs of the homotopy theoretic facts, "stripped" of the unnecessary details of real analysis (or category theoretical generalizations).

Comment: I gave a fairly comprehensive answer to [a different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469353/what-progress-made-in-automated-verification-of-mathematical-proofs) asked about the same time that in retrospect would have probably have been better here. More correct and larger, area-specific tags (e.g. logic) would have helped this question gain visibility to the relevant subcommunities.

Answer (score 4):

The paradigm shift here — which didn't originate with Voevodsky — is that *equivalence* is generally a more important notion than *equality*. There is a quirk that makes achieving the shift difficult: equivalence is often more complex than simply a yes/no proposition.

For example, in group theory, it's much more important to talk about whether two groups are *isomorphic* than whether they are *equal*. In fact, it's rather uncommon to do the latter.

As an example of the added complexity, consider the first isomorphism theorem of groups. The main conclusion is often stated as

> If $\varphi : G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, then $G/\ker(\varphi)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{im}(\varphi)$

but that's only part of what it says: the first isomorphism isn't merely saying "there is an isomorphism", but that the *specific function* $\overline{x} \mapsto \varphi(x)$ is said isomorphism.  (where $\overline{x}$ denotes the congruence class of $x$)

Talk of "changing the meaning of the equals sign" is, IMO, somewhat hyperbolic. Really, it's just describing the fact that if you have a way to reason and calculate in a way where *equivalence* really is the primary notion, it's useful to repurpose the symbol "=" to mean equivalence. (and if you really need the notion of equality, to find some other way to express it)

---

A great answer should mention homotopy type theory and/or the univalence axiom. It should also mutter something about the development of $\infty$-category theory and the search for internal languages, and also about the semantics of identity types in intensional type theory. I'm not ambitious enough to try and write a great answer, so I'll just mention the terms here to give hints for further reading.

Comment: Note I can't really speak as to what Voevodsky's contributions were.

Comment: It sounds like a good deal of this answer involves a shift from $\mathbf{Sets}$ (with Leibniz equality) to $\mathbf{Setoids}$.  (Another example often given: in classical mathematics we have *functional extensionality*: $(\forall x, f(x) = g(x)) \rightarrow f = g$.  While this is a natural equivalence to consider on function spaces, in computer science we're often concerned with algorithmic complexity of the implementations of $f$ and $g$ which isn't well-defined with respect to the "extensionally equal" equivalence.)  I'm not sure how much that has to do with homotopy type theory, though...

Comment: which as I understand it was in large part what Voevodsky's contributions were focused in.  (Not that I'm at all opposed to the shift from $\mathbf{Sets}$ to $\mathbf{Setoids}$ myself.)

Comment: So there is no answer.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Setoids are still "equivalence as a yes/no proposition". The example of groups up to isomorphism is already beyond that: the core of **Grp** is a groupoid that is not a setoid.